# Microsoft Teams DDI. I can call to outside numbers, But unable to receive calls

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, synchronization, microsoft-teams, group-policy

I have set up DDI numbers for my organization to receive inbound and outbound calls through MS Teams using a telephone number. I bought this from a telecom provider.

First I opened active directory and added the telephone number to the **Telephone Number** field and Added name "**Team**" to the pager section.
[image]

Then, wait couple of hours to sync the system.

I opened PowerShell and logged in to teams via PowerShell.
Then I entered below commands;

Set-CsUser -Identity '**<EMAIL_ADDRESS>**' -EnterpriseVoiceEnabled $true -HostedVoiceMail $true -OnPremLineURI 'tel:**+6XXXXXXXXX**'

Grant-CsTenantDialPlan -PolicyName **<POLICY_NAME>** -Identity '**<EMAIL_ADDRESS>**'

Grant-CsTeamsCallingPolicy -PolicyName AllowCalling -Identity '**<EMAIL_ADDRESS>**'

Grant-CsOnlineVoiceRoutingPolicy -PolicyName '**<POLICY_NAME_2>**' -Identity '**<EMAIL_ADDRESS>**'

I waited another 3,4 hours to sync and update group policies on devices using **gpupdate**

Now I can take call to outside using dial pad. But I am not receiving any calls from out side. When I tried, there is a recording going on. It says **"The number you have called is not currently active or is invalid. Please check the number and dial again"**. The number is working number.

Seeking advice from experts. Thank you.

Comment: Please have look at this document- https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp

Comment: Hi Sayali, I tried this. Didn’t work for me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is Direct Routing and using old instructions. This is the current one [Enable users for Direct Routing - Microsoft Teams | Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/direct-routing-enable-users)

There are some troubleshooting tips here [Monitor and troubleshoot Direct Routing - Microsoft Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/direct-routing-monitor-and-troubleshoot) including a diag tool that checks if the user is properly configured.

Since this is Direct Routing and inbound to Teams, the audio message can come from multiple components, i.e. carrier or us or somewhere a long the way.You can check your SBC to see if the call reaches it and if it does, check what error message Direct Routing is returning. The best approach is to open a Microsoft support case and provide the tenant information, call time, phone number etc and support can check Direct Routing traces etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this after investigating with Network team. There were 2 issues.

1. The Telephone Number field in the user profile on AD, we need to put the number as normal. Not as E. 164 standard. As an example: The number should be 0229188884 not like +64229188884
2. otherPager attribute field in the user profile on AD, We need to add as "teams" (LOWERCASE). I have added as "Teams".

I made those changes and wait for sync. Then trid to call to that number. It worked.

Thank you [@Sayali-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17300012/sayali-msft) for your support. I found some clues and got a clear path to investigate becasue of your guidance.